# microstratgy api call

Tags: sql, rest, azure-data-factory

I am trying to run the MicroStrategy api using adf and finding issue to pass the token into the future steps in webactivity.

I have  a two web activity one which gets me the token and one more  webactivity to run again another microstarty api call called https://demo.microstrategy.com/MicroStrategyLibrary/api-docs/index.html#/Events/triggerEvent .

The issue is i dont find any json for trigger event and i not sure how to pass the parameter in adf .
Could anyone help

i tried passing the header and i did falied , not sure how to pass it

Comment: can you add screenshots of your pipeline? and the token you are getting from first web activity where you are using it in header or body of second web activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but in the strategy's API, you will need to send the cookies, from the response, in the header of the next request. The cookies provided from the last request include session details such as the expiration time from your X-MSTR-AuthToken.

Check below some code I wrote in laravel to use the API.

login method:

```
public function Sauth($username, $password){

// building the request body; verify if it's possible to improve the 
formatting without compromising body requirements
$body='{"username":"'. "$username".'",
    '.
    '"password":"'."$password".'",
    "loginMode": 1
}';
$response= Strategy::withBody($body)->post('auth/login');

$this->XMSTRAuthToken = $response->header('X-MSTR-AuthToken');
$this->cookies = $response->cookies;

/** implement handling of the response to identify login failures
 * consider creating custom exceptions to throw in case of failure
 * return true to simplify logic in controllers that use this method
 **/
return true;
}
```

GET REPORT INSTANCE METHOD

```
public function getInstance(String $reportID)
{
// Getting the cookies
$cookies = $this->mapCookies($this->cookies);

// request
$response = Strategy::withHeaders([
    'X-MSTR-AuthToken' => $this->XMSTRAuthToken,
    'X-MSTR-ProjectID' => $this->ProjectId,
    'reportId' => $reportID,
    'Cookie' => $cookies // Sending the cookies in the 'Cookie' header
])->post("reports/$reportID/instances");
/**
 * Implement error handling in the response
 **/
return $response->json("instanceId");
}
```

AND THE COOKIE METHOD

```
private function mapCookies($cookies)
{
    return collect($cookies)->map(function ($cookie) {
        return $cookie->getName() . '=' . $cookie->getValue();
    })->implode('; ');
}
```